# How to add those tiny underlines for keyboard shortcuts when making right click menus from registry?

Tags: registry, contextmenu, customization

This is a picture of what I mean, There is no underline in the entry that I created, so I can't access it with keyboard shortcut directly:

[image]

Here's a picture of how I made it:

[image]

Comment: Usually you add an ampersand in front of the character you want to use as a mnemonic. I can't remember if this works in menu items added this way through the registry.

Comment: Thank you very much, It worked and i just asked this question.

Comment: Been searching MS dev center for an hour before deciding to finally ask here

Comment: You're welcome. I was on my phone earlier, but I looked again more carefully and didn't find a relevant duplicate for this, so if that worked for you, please feel free to post an answer below with the solution! Including some sample code (or the "value data") as plain text would make it an even better answer. You'll have to wait a bit, I believe, before the system will let you accept your own answer, but we encourage self-learning, so don't feel bashful about doing it. I certainly don't need the points. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This key did the job

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.ico\Shell\SetThisIcon]
@="Set This Icon For Current &Folder"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.ico\Shell\SetThisIcon\command]
@="cmd /c del folder.ico /f /a s & copy /y \"%1\" folder.ico & \"setI[enter image description here][1]con.bat\""
```

Just ignore the "command" key

ampersand before the letter that you want as shortcut:
`@="Set This Icon For Current &Folder"`
i.e. `&F`

[The Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfG2H.png)
[The Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sy9Us.png)